# sed removing # and ; comments from files up to certain keyword

Tags: bash, sed

I have files that need to be removed from comments and white space until keyword . Line number varies . Is it possible to limit multiple continued sed substitutions based on Keyword ?

This removes all comments and white spaces from file :

```
sed -i -e 's/#.*$//' -e 's/;.*$//' -e '/^$/d' file
```

For example something like this :

```
# string1 
# string2
some string
; string3

; string4
####

<Keyword_Keep_this_line_and_comments_white_space_after_this>
# More comments that need to be here

; etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -i '1,/keyword/{/^[#;]/d;/^$/d;}' file
```

Comment: Very nice . Many questions answered in one answer , thanks .

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using awk and setting a flag when you reach your keyword:

```
awk '/Keyword/ { stop = 1 } stop || !/^[[:blank:]]*([;#]|$)/' file
```

Set `stop` to true when the line contains `Keyword`. Do the default action (print the line) when `stop` is true or when the line doesn't match the regex. The regex matches lines whose first non-blank character is a semicolon or hash, or blank lines. It's slightly different to your condition but I think it does what you want.

The command prints to standard output so you should redirect to a new file and then overwrite the original to achieve an "in-place edit":

```
awk '...' input > tmp && mv tmp input
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep -n keyword` to get the line number that contains the keyword.

Use `sed -i -e '1,N s/#...`, when N is the line number that contains the keyword, to only remove comments on the lines 1 to N.